# creating sqlite table

Tags: android

This maybe a silly question but I am having trouble looking for the error. I am having a syntax error near "`TEXT`", but I don't know where. I am pretty sure that I typed this correctly.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_UNIQUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_FULLNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_BDAY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SEX + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_WORK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PROF + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_FBUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_FBPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_YMUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_YMPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_GMUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_GMPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SKUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SKPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );  
    }
```

Comment: Post your logcat. You've got about 20 "TEXT". Where's the error?

Comment: Its possible that one of your KEY_??? strings has a syntax error

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it just works fine,you can try code below(change the names of database,table and column as i have used test names)

```
public class dbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 // Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "temp_database";



private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="a";
private static final String KEY_ROWID ="b";
private static final String KEY_UNIQUE = "c";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "d";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "e";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "f";
private static final String KEY_FULLNAME = "g";
private static final String KEY_BDAY = "h";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "i";
private static final String KEY_SEX = "j";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "k";
private static final String KEY_WORK = "l";
private static final String KEY_PROF = "m";
private static final String KEY_FBUSERNAME = "n";
private static final String KEY_FBPASSWORD = "o";
private static final String KEY_YMPASSWORD = "p";
private static final String KEY_YMUSERNAME = "q";
private static final String KEY_GMUSERNAME = "r";
private static final String KEY_GMPASSWORD = "s";
private static final String KEY_SKUSERNAME = "t";
private static final String KEY_SKPASSWORD = "u";

public dbHandler(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.w("jndfjfs","this constructor is called");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_UNIQUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_FULLNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_BDAY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SEX + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_WORK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PROF + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_FBUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_FBPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_YMUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_YMPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_GMUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_GMPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SKUSERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SKPASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );  
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

you can access your database from other activity as,

```
dbHandler mydb=new dbHandler(this);
    mydb.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted Logcat, we can't catch the issue.

but, a handy suggestion: If you are expert in Database CRUD operation, then write query and execute it using [rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29) method.

```
db.rawQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (username TEXT, password TEXT)", null);
```